# Can I make the Shopping Cart step "mandatory" before going to Checkout (Magento 1.9)?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onestepcheckout, shopping

We have created a Coupon Code for free shipping, and our cart widget displays two buttons (links):

- one goes to the Shopping Cart screen (where people can enter the Cupon Code)
- the other goes to the One Page Checkout (where people cannot do it)

We'd like to make the Shopping Cart step mandatory, we thought about removing the Checkout links, but we want to make sure we have some setting / way to make it a mandatory step anyways.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Generally one step checkout extension have also coupen cope apply block on checkout page, you can enable so your above issues is resolve.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, I'm using Magento's default one step checkout, and I can't find where to enable the coupon code there. Should I go and download an extension? Unfortunately Magento's 1+ extensions are closed on their repository. Do you have any idea about what to do? Thanks,

Comment: If you are using defult, then no options there, so you need to do some customization there.